# Can an infant travel anywhere on a parent's passport?

Tags: passports, children

I have heard that some decades ago, infants could travel with a parent without needing a passport of their own. Is that still true anywhere? I.e. is there any situation where an adult needs a passport to travel, but their child can accompany them without their own passport?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this was generally possible only if the child was listed in the parent's passport.

Comment: There are about 195 countries to have passports from and 194 countries to travel to, which makes this about 40,000 possible combos not counting multiple citizenship, parent/infants with different citizenship(s), means of transportation etc..  All of these can potentially have different rules. Are you looking for a specific combo that requires passport for parents but not for children? For example, that's true for Canadians entering the US by land or sea. Kids don't need a passport, but a may need a birth certificate

Comment: @Hilmar what's the one country that issues passports but to which one cannot travel?

Comment: It is becoming more difficult, so better to have the infant passport. And increasing number of countries requires also the two parents or some official paperwork. So passport is not the only problem.

Comment: @phoog I think he's saying that there are 195 countries that one could have a passport from, but as a passport holder of any country there are 194 other countries you could travel to.

Comment: @phoog: The Sovereign Military Order of Malta, perhaps?

Comment: Generally, infants do have to have passports now. It's usually not that big of a hassle to get a passport (unless you're a citizen of a country like Syria or Somalia), so why not?

Comment: @phoog: you can't travel to the county that you are already in :-)

Answer (score 3):

Modern "biometric" passports just don't have children section anymore, so it's not possible to add children there, and a separate passport (with separate visa) is required. Maybe it's just Russian passports, though.

Comment: Same in Dutch passports I know for sure and I have heard the same about more countries.

Comment: If it's true of Dutch passports it's probably true of all EU passports. I also know for sure that this is the case in a few countries.